# i cannot able to get data from API in brand and models concept.. onchange brand it should get Models details from API and show in model select

Tags: php, codeigniter

i had used codeignator for this project we are getting brand from

```
<select name="brandId" onchange="getModel(this.value);" required>
  <option value ="2">select</option>
  <?php foreach($masterlist['result']['brand'] as $key => $value) { ?>                                                          
    <option value= "<?php  echo $value['brand_id'] ;?>">
    <?php  echo $value['brand_name'] ;?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

and this is the function

```
 function getModel(value){
    $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
           url: "<?php echo site_url().'/welcome/getvehicleModel/'?>"
           data: data,
           success: function(response){  
            console.log(response);              
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: change `data: data,` to `data: {'id':value},` and show the console messgae

Comment: ya thank you...problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

success: function(response){

```
                console.log(response.result[0]['model_id']);
                if(response.result){
                for(i=0;i<response.result.length;i++){

                var opt = new Option(response.result[i]['model_name'],response.result[i]['model_id']);
                    $("#model").append(opt);

                    }
                }
```